# ngx-toastr error in loading not found angular 5 firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, toastr

I am trying to use ngx-toastr in creating a crud application for angular and firebase, when i use ng serve i get the below error. i have installed the module but still i get that module not found.

```
Date: 2018-06-07T13:53:43.913Z - Hash: 0b3a54d751a65a6229b2 - Time: 533ms5 unchanged chunks

ERROR in multi ./src/styles.css ./src/node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\Projects\angularfirebasecrud\src\node_modules\ngx-toastr\toastr.css' in 'D:\Projects\angularfirebasecrud'

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: did you import the module in your module.ts?

Comment: Yes, i have done that

Comment: can you post related code